# How can I grab a list of games by Google Play Gamer ID?

Tags: api, google-play-games

I am trying to figure out how I can retrieve the list of games owned by a person by their Google Play Gamer ID. I remember that I saw the exact answer and code example somewhere on Google's API documentation or n their help center but I have spent half a day today and couldn't find it again. It's probably somewhere [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api) and I just keep overlooking it.
I know that it is definitely possible not only because I saw it but also there are some products that actually use this function. Like this one → https://www.exophase.com

It doesn't have to be a list of games, a list of achievements gained by a person is also fine (since you can link achievements to games).

Comment: Did you find a solution for fetching games?